# Jest : How to mock vue-router used in vuex

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-router

I tried to use vue-router inside actions of vuex, which is working fine at localhost.

However, i got errors when I tried to prepare store(for mock) by importing "actions" from store file.

Could you help me out in this issue?

---

---

**versions**

```
vue-test-utils: 1.0.0-beta.16
yarn: 1.5.1
vuejs: 2.5.13
vue-jest: 1.4.0
```

**error msg**

```
 FAIL  test/components/main.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/gulliver/Desktop/test/vue-test-utils-jest-example/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:10809
    export default Vue$3;
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:305:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/router/main.js:1:203)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/main.js:3:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.354s
Ran all test suites matching /test\/components\/main.test.js/i.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
```

---

---

**app/src/main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue/dist/vue.esm";
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store/main.js';
import router from './router/main.js';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  store,
  router,
})
```

**app/src/store/main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import router from '../router/main.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const actions = {
  locationTo(context, url){
    router.push(url)  
  }
}
export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions,
})
```

**app/src/router/main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue/dist/vue.esm";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import root from '../components/root.vue';
import hoge from '../components/hoge.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: root},
  { path: '/hoge', component: hoge},
];

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
```

**app/test/components/main.test.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";

import { actions } from "@/store/main"; //NOTE: this causes error

import _ from "lodash";
const localVue = createLocalVue();

import root from '@/components/root.vue'
import hoge from '@/components/hoge.vue'

describe('increment.vue', () => {
  let propsData;
  let store;
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    propsData = _.cloneDeep(personObject)

    store = new Vuex.Store(_.cloneDeep({
      actions,
    }))

    const $route = {
      path: '/hoge', components: hoge
    }

    wrapper = shallowMount(root, {
      localVue,
      propsData,
      store,
      use: ['Vuex'],
      stubs: ['router-view'],
      mocks: {
        $route
      }
    })

  });

  it('test:router in store', () => {
    // check if URL changed after action executed
  });

})
```

components

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

// root.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <p>root component</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('locationTo', '/hoge')
  },
}
</script>

// hoge.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <p>hoge template</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the fact that Jest runs in a Node.js environment, and you are using `export default`, which does not work by default in Node.js (Node uses `module.exports`). I guess you are using webpack for your dev/production build, but not for the test environment.

Are you using Jest? If so, you will need to set up `babel-jest` so Jest knows how to read ES Modules syntax (`import/export`).

Read more here: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-single-file-components-with-jest

This can be annoying to set up, let me know if you need more help to get it working.